# Yum Update ansible version

Tags: pip, ansible, centos7, yum

I have ansible version 1.9 on my Centos 7 machine, but need to get version 1.9.2 as I'm running into compatibility issues with ansible and docker.

However, doing a yum update on the ansible package has no affect:

```
yum update -y ansible
No packages marked for update
```

How can I upgrade the package?

**Edit:**

I have upgraded the package using pip as suggested by @Eldad AK:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ansible==1.9.2
```

And the upgrade appeared to be successful:

> Successfully installed MarkupSafe-0.23 ansible-1.9.2 ecdsa-0.13 jinja2-2.8 paramiko-1.16.0 setuptools-20.7.0

However when i run the ansible executable and check the version, it's still at 1.9:

```
ansible --version
ansible 1.9 (devel affb66416f) last updated 2015/11/04 09:09:40 (GMT +100)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can upgrade it using `pip`. Try

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ansible
```

This is how we update Ansible.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Getting below error
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-EKrsJU/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZYCjVT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EKrsJU/cryptography/

Answer (score 1):

You probably have two versions of ansible installed:

- **1.9 installed via yum**. Which is the one in your path and probably in /usr/bin/ansible.
- **1.9.2 installed via pip**. Check /usr/lib/python-*version*/site-packages/, I guess there is an ansible-1.9.2-* directory there.

You can either uninstall the first one or include the second one in you PATH with a higher precedence.

A quick and dirty fix would be:

`mv /usr/bin/ansible /usr/bin/ansible1.9 && mv /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /usr/bin/ansible-playbook1.9`

`ln -s /usr/lib/python-<version>/ansible-1.9.2-py[...].egg/EGG/scripts/ansible /usr/bin/ansible`

`ln -s /usr/lib/python-<version>/ansible-1.9.2-py[...].egg/EGG/scripts/ansible-playbook /usr/bin/ansible-playbook`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall ansible

sudo python -m pip install ansible
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it